# How to remove mountain shades from Roadmap view (zoom level <13)

Tags: css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, styles, layer

I would like to remove the mountains shades in the regular Roadmap map type.

Below zoomlevel 13 the Roadmap view shows mountain/hill/elevation shades to give a somewhat 3D experience on the map. When you zoom in to zoom level 13 and higher, the mountain shades are removed by Google Maps. It seems to me this is  separate layer that Google overlays themselves when you zoom out to 12, 11 etc - but I haven't identified it yet.

Does anybody know whether I can manipulate the styling at, for example, zoomlevel 11 or 12, to get the flat surface view of zoomlevel 13 and higher?

For a certain graphical purpose I would like to have the real flat surface view experience of the z13/and closer in a zoomlevel of 11 or 12.

See included images to show the difference of what I mean:

Zoomlevel 12, mountain shades

[image]

Zoomlevel 13, without mountain shades, flat surface

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.  Have you looked at the Google Maps Javascript API v3 or Embedded Map API?

Comment: I did not code anything yet in this regard. As far as I am concerned I am asking whether it is technically possible *at all* to remove the mountain shade overlay on other zoomlevels under Z13 (Z11, etc) as explained, differences shown. 

I cannot find this in documentation, nor can I find whether this shade diff as illustrated is embedded in GM graphics (& thus cannot be removed). Now, I am not a perfect person, so maybe I have overlooked the documentation. If code is mandatory, I'll have a try. 

Thank you for chiming in.

Comment: How are you viewing the map?  How are you planning on displaying it on your web page?

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out it can be done through a custom map type, setting this styling property (among others):

```
    {
      featureType: 'landscape',
      elementType: 'geometry',
      stylers: [
        {
            color:'#f3f3f2',
          visibility: 'off'
        }
      ]
    },
```

Will play around for some more customization, but here is a sample of my code (added for others to check in JSFiddle):

```
function initMap() {

  var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(
      [
        {elementType: 'labels.text.fill', stylers: [{color: '#523735'}]},
        {elementType: 'labels.text.stroke', stylers: [{color: '#f5f1e6'}]},
        {
          featureType: 'administrative',
          elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
          stylers: [{color: '#ff0000'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'administrative.province',
          elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
          stylers: [
            {
              visibility: 'off'
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'landscape',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [
            {
                color:'#f3f3f2',
              visibility: 'off'
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'poi',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'poi',
          elementType: 'labels',
          stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#f5f1e6'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.arterial',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#999900'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.highway',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#f8c967'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.highway',
          elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
          stylers: [{color: '#e9bc62'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.highway.controlled_access',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#e98d58'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.highway.controlled_access',
          elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
          stylers: [{color: '#db8555'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.local',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#806b63'}]
        }
      ],
      {name: 'Styled Map'});

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 42.37, lng: 44.01},
    zoom: 9,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: ['roadmap', 'satellite', 'hybrid', 'terrain',
              'styled_map']
    }
  });

  map.mapTypes.set('styled_map', styledMapType);
  map.setMapTypeId('styled_map');
}
```

Comment: To "close" this, [accept](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) your answer.

Comment: Sure. Saturday. Thanks.